# Zxing error on API 23: No Activity found to Handle intent act = "com.google.zxing.client.SCAN"

Tags: android, zxing

I am using Zxing in my Application to scan QRcode but it only runs on API 26 or Later. When I run it on API 23 or 24 it gives error: No Activity found to handle intent: "com.google.zxing.client.SCAN".
My minsdk version is 23 and target and compiled version is 28.

**Please Help and if possible tell me how to use zxing on lower api devices.**

**Android Mainfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sync_remote_and_local_mysql_db_php">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Intent Calling function**

```
public void HandlingClick(View arg0) {

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0); //Barcode Scanner to scan for us
}
```

**Logcat**

```
    06-16 12:07:31.517 18299-18299/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-16 12:07:31.538 18299-18299/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
06-16 12:07:31.544 18299-18299/? W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
        at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
        at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5587)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
06-16 12:07:31.575 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.barcode_online_scan-2/lib/arm64
06-16 12:07:31.613 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-16 12:07:31.629 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan D/AccessibilityManager: current package=com.example.barcode_online_scan, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=false, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
06-16 12:07:31.636 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@3454e9
06-16 12:07:31.636 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@d5d556e
06-16 12:07:31.639 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
06-16 12:07:31.639 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
06-16 12:07:31.676 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:1406349
06-16 12:07:31.676 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan 
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-16 12:07:31.677 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.barcode_online_scan, PID: 18299
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.barcode_online_scan/com.example.barcode_online_scan.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }
       at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5604)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4028)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3989)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at com.example.barcode_online_scan.MainActivity.HandlingClick(MainActivity.java:79)
        at com.example.barcode_online_scan.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6358)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5604) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
06-16 12:07:31.705 18299-18299/com.example.barcode_online_scan I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18299 SIG: 9
```

**Gradle(Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.barcode_online_scan"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner                
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    //add this line
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-    
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive = false }

}
```

**Gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    //add this dependency

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add required activity in your Manifest explicitly:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It's now showing a blank white screen. Am I missing any permissions... though I ask for camera permissions in my code. I have added my manifest in the question.

Comment: Register `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>` in the Manifest too

Comment: Still blank white screen.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.sync_remote_and_local_mysql_db_php/com.example.sync_remote_and_local_mysql_db_php.MainActivity}